# Add styling to form.as_div in Django

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I am rendering a model form in Django using {{ form.as_div  }}

It is rendering as expected as I want each field wrapped in a div.

I would now like to add a class to this auto generated div.

adding widgets in the forms.py file only adds attribute to the input field itself and not the div around the field.

Can someone point me in the right direction to add attributes to the div instead of the input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{{ form.as_div }} is not possible in Django but, you can do like this

====== in views.py =========

```
def DemoView(request):
    form = StudentForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'demo.html',context)
```

======= in html file ========

```
<h1>Student Form</h1>
<form action="" method="get" >
    {% for fm in form %}
        <div>
            <label>{{fm.label}}</label>
            <p>{{fm}} </p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

======= Output =========

[image]

Answer (score 0):

since django 4.1 you can use ["as_div"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options)!

I myself need this possibility in an earlier Version so i built myself an abstract Formclass containing my version of "as_div" derived from the existing render-functions:

```
class DivRenderer():
   """
    as_div: abstract class 
   """
   def as_div(self):
       "Return this form rendered as HTML <divs>s - according to client-Layout."
       return self._html_output(
           normal_row='<div class="form-group input" %(html_class_attr)s> %(errors)s%(field)s%(help_text)s %(label)s</div>',
           error_row='<div%s</div>',
           row_ender='</div>',
           help_text_html='<br><span class="helptext">%s</span>',
           errors_on_separate_row=False,
       )
   pass
```

and than using it simply while defining my forms like:

```
class someThingForm(forms.ModelForm, DivRenderer):
    readonly = …
    …
```

and than just using {{ form.as_div }} in the Templates

However!: The as_div-function is different as the one from 4.1 -  so be careful not to expect the same behaviour!

hope it helps

Karl